# Cannot POST /userslist in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I am very new to node js. I have made an application, where when admin logs in, it is showing 'Cannot POST /userslist', but once I refresh the page, it is fetching the userslist, following is the routing code for admin-

admin.js-

```
module.exports = function(app)
{   
    app.get('/adminedit', function (req, res) {      
        res.render('adminedit', { });
    });

    app.get('/userslist', function (req, res) {      
        res.render('userslist', { });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have used app.get for userslists

Comment: @maria.m — … which is the problem.

Comment: @maria.m but in question you write `POST /userslist` not `GET`

Comment: so, why are you trying to use post? Did you try to change to app.post(...)

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way to achieve your goal (using express) is:

- create a single service (called for example listUsers) in this way:

  ```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();

  router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

     User.find(function (err, users) {
       if(err) return res.json({success: false, message: err});
       res.json({success: true, userlist: users});
     )};
  });
  module.exports = router;
  ```

then you can use this service in app.js in this way:

```
var userListService = require('./routes/listUsers');
app.use('/listUsers', userListService);
```

at this point if you try to call in POST /listUsers, everything should work fine.